# typescript accepts unary fn although typed binary

Tags: typescript

I don't understand why TypeScript doesn't complain when parsing this:

```
type numNumToNum = (x: number, y: number) => number;
const add3 : numNumToNum = n => n+3;
```

The type alias `numNumToNum` is defined as a binary function on numbers. But add3 accepts a unary function although (wrongly) typed as numNumToNum.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think about it this way, if we define the function to be

`const add3 : numNumToNum = (n, notUsed) => n+3`

Does it satisfy the interface? it does. So just imagine the `notUsed` variable is already there. Not forcing the developer to add useless parameters is a feature, not a bug.

More strictly speaking, type `B` implements type `A` if we can pass object of type `B` to a consumer of `A`, and the consumer won't know the difference. Which is exactly the case here.

```
type numNumToNum = (x: number, y: number) => number;
const add3 : numNumToNum = n => n+3;

function applyNumNumToNum(fn: numNumToNum, a: number, b: number): number {
  return fn(a,b);
}

const foo: number = applyNumNumToNum((x,y) => x*y, 2,3); //this is valid
const bar: number = applyNumNumToNum(add3, 2,100000); //this is also valid. applyNumNumToNum doesn't care about our implementation and the fact that `1000000` isn't used
```

If you really want to enforce the number of parameters, you can always pass the parameters wrapped in an object or an array.

Wrapping parameters in an Object:

```
type numNumToNum = ({x: number, y: number}) => number;
const add3: numNumToNum = ({x,y}: {x: number, y: number}) => x+y+3;
```

Array (tuples):

```
type numNumToNum = (xy: [number, number]) => number;
const add3: numNumToNum = ([x, y]: [number, number]) => x+y+3;
```

Comment: So what I could do is: `type pairOfNumbers = [number, number];
type numNumToNum = (xy:pairOfNumbers) => number;
const add : numNumToNum = (xy:pairOfNumbers): number => xy[0] + xy[1];`

Comment: @TerenceS. yes, you are correct. See my edit.

I personally prefer wrapping in objects over arrays, because the parameter names can provide some documentation, but I guess for math functions work as well. (and in any case, this is a matter of personal preference)

Comment: But one problem remains: I wrapped all my parameters in an object or tupel but I could still define a function that takes no parameters at all:
`const add : numNumToNum = () => 42` ...